# Inequality - Find what value of $t$ satisfies: $ (t/24) - (t+1) + (3t/8) < (5/12) (t+1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Inequality - Find what value of $t$ satisfies:  $(t/24) - (t+1) + (3t/8) < (5/12) (t+1)$.

Step 1: I multiplied both sides by $24$ and divided to get: $t-24(t+1)+9t < 10+24(t+1)$.
Step 2: I multiplied $(t+1)$ on both sides with -24 and +24 and got: $t-24t+24+9t < 10+24t+24$.
Step 3: Simplified this into: $-14t+24 < 34+24t$.
Step 4: Added $14t-34$ on both sides. I was left with: $-10 < 38t$.
Step 5: Divided both sides by $38$ gives: $-5/19 < t$.

I also tried moving $(t+1)$ to one side so I got: $-(t+1)^2$. Where I got: $-24t^2-38t<34$. Then I divided by $-38$ where I also changed the sign: $-12/19t^2+t>-17/-19$. From this point I couldn't get just $(t)$ on one side because of that $t^2$.

Both of them are incorrect. What did I do wrong?

Comment: By $x$ you mean $t$, right?

Comment: Yes, thank you, edited.

Comment: in step 1, + is missing before 9 and rhs should be 10(t+1)

Comment: That's a type mistake, thanks edited. In the calculation further you can see +9t. For lhs I multiplied 5/12 by 24 and divided by 12 and got 10. (t+1) was not multiplied by 24 yet. So I put the 24 there. Shouldn't I have done that?

Comment: we can not multiply one term on rhs and one term on lhs, we have to multiply entire rhs and lhs side with the same expression for the inequality to remain same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{t}{24}-(t+1)+\frac{3t}{8}<\frac{5}{12}(t+1)$

$t-24(t+1)+9t<10(t+1)$

$10t<34(t+1)$

$10t<34t+34$

$-24t<34$

$t>-\frac{17}{12}$

Comment: Please fix the $<$ for a $>$ in the last expression.

Comment: Ah oke, so I shouldn't have multiplied (t+1) by 24. But what I don't understand is what happened to -(t+1) on the left side. O wait... so -24(t+1) is added to 10(t+1). Ok, I get it now, big thanks!

Comment: @rlartiga, thanx

Comment: @user160137, we added 24(t+1) on both the sides

Answer (score 2):

$\large \frac{t}{24} -(t+1) + \large \frac{3t}{8} \lt \frac{5}{12}(t+1)$

$\implies \large \frac{t}{24} -t +\large \frac{3t}{8}-1 \lt \large \frac{5t+5}{12}$

$\implies \large \frac{t-24t+9t-24}{24} \lt \frac{5t+5}{12}$

$\implies -14t-24<10t+10$

Collect All $t$ on LHS.

$-24t \lt 34$

Once you multiply by -1 both sides, the equality sign turns opposite.

So,

$t>\large \frac{-34}{24}$

$\implies t>\large \frac{-17}{12}$ or $-1.42$

So for values, greater than $-1.42$ your equality holds true.

CHECK:

Try substituting $t=-1$ and see what happens.

Comment: You had it right the first time it's -24t instead of -14t. The answer is -17/12. I prefer to solve it as Vikram did. Seems a lot easier to me :) Thanks for showing me a different approach and the check! +1.

Comment: Sometimes I get confused doing the math in the head and working at my office. So yeah! maybe because of that.I'll fix it. Glad to know it helps you.